# How to implement jquery and Mootools together?

Tags: jquery

I am developing a website in which I am implementing two slider for images gallery using one with jQuery and one with moottools. But there is problem in implementing these because when I use both together the jQuery slider doesn't works where mootools slider works. jQuery slider works in case where I remove mootools. What should I do to implement both sliders together? Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.slideviewer.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Syntax hl -->
<script src="js/jquery.syntax.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $("div#mygaltop").slideView({toolTip: true, ttOpacity: 0.5});   
    $("div#mygalone").slideView(); //if leaved blank performs the default kind of animation (easeInOutExpo, 750)
    $("div#mygaltwo").slideView({
        easeFunc: "easeInOutBounce",
        easeTime: 2200,
        toolTip: true
    }); 
    $("div#mygalthree").slideView({
        easeFunc: "easeInOutSine",
        easeTime: 100,
        uiBefore: true,
        ttOpacity: 0.5,
        toolTip: true
    });
});

$(function(){
$.syntax({root: 'http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/themes/giancarlo-mingati/js/jquery-syntax/'});
});

</script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/product.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/scroll.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link href="css/ieonly.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-1.2-core.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/SlideItMoo.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    /* thumbnails example , links only */
    new SlideItMoo({itemsVisible:5, // the number of thumbnails that are visible
                    currentElement: 0, // the current element. starts from 0. If you want to start the display with a specific thumbnail, change this
                    thumbsContainer: 'thumbs',
                    elementScrolled: 'thumb_container',
                    overallContainer: 'gallery_container'});

    /* thumbnails example , div containers */
    new SlideItMoo({itemsVisible:5, // the number of thumbnails that are visible
                    currentElement: 0, // the current element. starts from 0. If you want to start the display with a specific thumbnail, change this
                    thumbsContainer: 'thumbs2',
                    elementScrolled: 'thumb_container2',
                    overallContainer: 'gallery_container2'});

    /* banner rotator example */
    new SlideItMoo({itemsVisible:1, // the number of thumbnails that are visible
                    showControls:0, // show the next-previous buttons
                    autoSlide:2500, // insert interval in milliseconds
                    currentElement: 0, // the current element. starts from 0. If you want to start the display with a specific thumbnail, change this
                    transition: Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut,
                    thumbsContainer: 'banners',
                    elementScrolled: 'banner_container',
                    overallContainer: 'banners_container'});
});
</script>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="landing">

        <!-- landing page menu -->
            <div id="landing_menu">

                <ul>

                    <li><a class="active" href="#">SPECIALS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SHOP MEN'S</a></li>
                  <li class="none"><a class="none" href="#">SHOP WOMEN'S</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>


        <!-- landing page menu -->


        <!-- loading container menu -->

        <div id="container_part">
            <div id="big_image_slider">
            <!-- <img src="images/briteloves.png" alt="Britelove" /> -->

                  <div id="mygaltop" class="svw">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/briteloves.png" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/1.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/2.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/3.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/4.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/5.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/6.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/7.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/8.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/9.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/10.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/11.jpg" /></li>
                        <li><img alt="Tresmode | Footwear &amp; Accessories"  src="images/12.jpg" /></li>


                    </ul>
                 </div>


            </div>

            <div class="new_style_banner"><img src="images/new_styles.png" alt="new style" /></div>

            <div class="new_style_banner"><img src="images/ford-super-models.png" alt="ford super models" /></div>
        </div>

        <!--- loading container menu -->


        <!-- footer scrool --->

        <div id="footer_scroll">

            <!--thumbnails slideshow begin-->
            <div id="gallery_container">    
        <div id="thumb_container">          
            <div id="thumbs">
                <a href="gallery/full/DC080302018.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/1.jpg"/></a> 
                <a href="gallery/full/DC080302028.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/2.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="gallery/full/DC080302030.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/3.jpg"/></a>
                        <a href="gallery/full/DC080302018.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/4.jpg" /></a>    
                <a href="gallery/full/DC080302028.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/5.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="gallery/full/DC080302030.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/6.jpg"/></a>

                <a href="gallery/full/DC080302018.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/1.jpg"/></a> 
                <a href="gallery/full/DC080302028.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/2.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="gallery/full/DC080302030.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/7.jpg"/></a>
                        <a href="gallery/full/DC080302018.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/8.jpg" /></a>    
                <a href="gallery/full/DC080302028.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/9.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="gallery/full/DC080302030.jpg" rel="lightbox[galerie]" target="_blank"><img src="gallery/thumb/10.jpg"/></a>


            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>  
            <!--thumbnails slideshow end-->


        </div>

        <!-- foooter scrooll -->




    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-2064812-2");
pageTracker._initData();
pageTracker._trackPageview();
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Any use of "$" for referring to jQuery on the javascript global scope must be replaced with "jQuery" and you must call jQuery.noConflict() prior to any jQuery or mootool call.  Inside jQuery methods you can continue to use $ and there shouldn't be any problem.

**Edit** - The resulting script for you would be:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
    $("div#mygaltop").slideView({toolTip: true, ttOpacity: 0.5});   
    $("div#mygalone").slideView(); //if leaved blank performs the default kind of animation (easeInOutExpo, 750)
    $("div#mygaltwo").slideView({
        easeFunc: "easeInOutBounce",
        easeTime: 2200,
        toolTip: true
    }); 
    $("div#mygalthree").slideView({
        easeFunc: "easeInOutSine",
        easeTime: 100,
        uiBefore: true,
        ttOpacity: 0.5,
        toolTip: true
    });
});

jQuery(function(){
    $.syntax({root: 'http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/themes/giancarlo-mingati/js/jquery-syntax/'});
});
```

Comment: how can i used this code with my code because i try to use it with my code it's having problem..

Comment: @Avi Kumar Manku: Modified original answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have found that you need to call in MooTools before jQuery if you want to include both libraries. Then use the jQuery.noConflict().